# CSS not showing up in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a css file, home_page.css.scss, in `app/assets/stylesheets`, and added the tag `<% stylesheet_link_tag 'home_page.css'  %>` to my html.erb file, named `index.html.erb`.

When I run the rails server (after restarting so that the CSS can compile) I can see the HTML content of my page at `localhost:3000`, but the CSS content is no where to be found.

The entire source code of my rails app can be viewed on my GitHub if that helps:

https://github.com/adam-wanninger/tweet_down

What am I doing wrong?

Here is `index.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <% stylesheet_link_tag 'home_page.css'  %>
  <title>Tweet Down</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Tweet Down</h1>

<p>Tweet Down is a Ruby on Rails app built by me, Adam Wanninger. I built Tweet Down to be a basic (but stylish) Twitter feed for next years presidential candidates.</p>

<div>
  <p id="dem_drop_down">Democratic Party Candidates<br>
    <select name="democrat_menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
      <option selected="selected">Bernie Sanders</option>
      <option value="year/1">Hillary Clinton</option>
      <option value="year/2">Michael Jackson</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="rep_drop_down">Republican Party Candidates<br>
    <select name="republican_menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
      <option selected="selected">Ted Cruz</option>
      <option value="URL">Jeb Bush</option>
      <option value="URL">Jon Stamos</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>




</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% stylesheet_link_tag 'home_page.css'  %>
```

is missing the `=` at the beginning.

Try

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home_page.css'  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of `index.html.erb` is actually yielded to the body of `application.html.erb`.  So you would probably want to include only the part of `index.html.erb` that starts with the `<h1>` in the `index.html.erb` file.

**Edit**

So in your `/app/views/layouts` folder there is `application.html.erb`.  `application.html.erb` is the default layout for the site.  I am not sure why you did this, but you changed

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

By doing this, you overrode the automatic inclusion of CSS files from `/app/assets/stylesheets`.

If you change it back, then `home_page.css` should automatically be included in the assets.

Now, if you look at the contents of `application.html.erb` you will see it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TweetDown</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Where it says `<%= yield %>` is where the entire contents of `index.html.erb` is output.  So with the `index.html.erb` that you have, you will have incorrect (non-validating) HTML.  You should change your `index.html.erb` to just have the section of HTML that you want in your body.  And after you change where you put `default` instead of `application` in your stylesheet and javascript declarations, it should still work.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't quite understand what you mean... could you please provide an example?

Comment: @FluffyKittens I updated the answer to provide more details.

Comment: Ahh, I had to change 'application' to default on this page because I was getting an error. I googled the error and from what I could ascertain it was a problem that many developers using Rails on Windows had encountered. However, I can change it back and see if the error still persists.